# Fifth time getting notified about an Internal Error in Ubuntu Server. Should I be worried about it?

Tags: 22.04

I'm new to Ubuntu, so please forgive me if this is a dumb question.

I have Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS at the moment, and I keep getting notified about this error:

[image: internal error notification image]

Restarting it doesn't stop the notifications.

Comment: You've tagged your question as being about Ubuntu 12.04???  How does that relate, given you mention 22.04 ?   Have you tried deleting the .crash file (`/var/crash/`) or uploading it? as the bug-nagging will stop after reporting/deletion